How to execute NDK/Clang in Android 11 using Java to compile C++ code within app environment?
I'm working on an Android app that needs to compile C++ code using the NDK and Clang(linux). In Android 11, I'm unable to execute Clang directly from internal storage due to storage and execution restrictions. Even though I have the NDK and Clang binaries placed in internal storage, when I try to execute them, I get permission errors.
I am currently trying to use ProcessBuilder to execute Clang like this:
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("/data/data/<my-app>/files/clang", "<source-file>.cpp", "-o", "<output>");
processBuilder.directory(new File("/data/data/<my-app>/files/"));
processBuilder.start();

However, I keep running into permission issues.
The error everytime shows like:
/system/bin/sh: ./clang++: can't execute: Permission denied

I would like to know:

How can I create a custom environment using Java within my app to execute Clang and compile C++ files?

Is there a way to bypass the restrictions of executing binaries in internal storage on Android 11?

Would using a chroot or similar environment inside my app help resolve this, and how can I set it up without requiring root access?

Are there any Android APIs or workarounds for invoking Clang or other native binaries securely in the app's private directory (/data/data//files/)?


Any suggestions or alternative approaches to achieve this in Android 11+?

Have you set he executable bit on the binaries you want to execute? What Android version do you use for testing? AFAIR there is a limitation that prevents execution of binaries from directories where the app has write permissions since Android 13 or 14.

yes i have set setExecutable(true); But still it shows same.I using Android version 11

Should i use a custom environment to do that??
